# applying angular directives to a set of elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to disable all of the form elements in a large form with many tabs when a certain condition is true.  I could use something like `<input ng-disabled="myCondition()">` but I'd need to add that in quite a few places and that seems like bad code duplication.  After some consideration I decided to go with the following in my controller.  (I'm using coffeescript btw)

```
$scope.$watch 'myCondition()', ->
  if $scope.myCondition()
    $('.my-form').find('input, select, textarea').attr('disabled', true)
  else
    $('.my-form').find('input, select, textarea').attr('disabled', false)
```

This works but it seems brittle.  If for example I have some other reason that a form element will need to be conditionally disabled then this may behave strangely.  What is the correct way to do this.  Does it have to do with `$compile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to *disable* a set of inputs (title is a bit misleading in this case) you can try the `<fieldset>`:

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="common.condition">
    <input ng-model="input1" ... />
    <input ng-model="input2" ... />
    ...
</fieldset>
```

They will all be disabled.

Comment: Nice! I was worried that I might be prevented from nesting `fieldset`s which would make this not work here but it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a custom directive for that. For example something like this:

```
app.directive('disableElements', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var elements = angular.element(element[0].querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select'));

            scope.$watch(attrs.disableElements, function(newVal) {
                elements.prop('disabled', !!newVal);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And use it like this:

```
<form disable-elements="condition">
    ...
</form>
```

The benefit is that you can select elements you want to disable inside a directive, for example of certain class. If you however want to disable all elements within a form you should definetely go with `fieldset` approach proposed by Nikos.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/pQkdQvABAytudRhC8bw2?p=preview